# How to structure pagination state in Redux

Tags: reactjs, pagination, redux, react-redux

**TL;DR:** How do you store pagination state in a Redux store given a large, normalized state tree with lots of resources, and multiple views displaying different paginated results?

I'm wondering what is the best way to store pagination data in a Redux store. [This article](https://techblog.appnexus.com/five-tips-for-working-with-redux-in-large-applications-89452af4fdcb) prescribes storing pagination info as its own subtree within the state tree. I agree with that method, but here's where I disagree: the article suggests keying the pagination subtree by the type of resource being paginated, but what if there are several views that display paginated data of the same resource using different parameters? If you follow the article's method, your state tree may end up looking like this

```
{
  pagination: 
     todos: 
       count: 1000,
       nextPageUrl: ...,
       result: [list of id's]
     users:
       count: 200,
       nextPageUrl: ...,
       result: [list of id's]
}
```

This doesn't seem to make sense to me if you have multiple ways to view the same resource. What if on one screen there are multiple tables displaying todos that were fetched using different parameters? For instance, one table displays todos that were fetched from `/api/todos/?userId=1` and another displays todos from `/api/todos/?userId=2`.

Given the above problem, it seems that a solution for allowing more flexible pagination is to store pagination state on a per-component basis, rather than a per-entity basis. So your state could look something like this

```
{
  pagination:
    componentId:
       count: 1000,
       nextPageUrl: ...,
       result: [list of id's]
    anotherComponentId:
       count: 1000,
       nextPageUrl: ...,
       result: [list of id's]
}
```

Of course, storing pagination results like this loses context as to what is being paginated. But is that so much of a problem? How do you go about paginating a large state tree with potentially multiple paginated results of the same resource? Thanks!

Comment: I try not to think in terms of entities, resources, and components so much as views.  So each view can get it's own pagination.  I think it's similar to the second example above, except it's not 1:1 tied to a component.  For example you could have a TodoList component that has multiple different views (i.e. it is displayed in different places on the page with different context in each place).

Comment: That's what I'm thinking too, but I'm not sure how that component can create it's unique pagination key within the Redux state. If you put multiple TodoList components within a page, what would the `mapStateToProps` function look like? Would the parent component supply each TodoList component with a unique `key` prop that the component uses within `mapStateToProps` to grab the pagination state?

Comment: I think each view gets it's own reducer, and with combineReducers each view gets it's own slice of the state.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think that [redux-cached-pagination](https://github.com/Tranzystor/redux-cached-pagination) ([Demo here](https://tranzystor.github.io/redux-cached-pagination/#/)) can help to cope with your problem. Normalized search results are stored in redux in a tree like that:

```
{
  standard_store: {
    pagination: {
      searchPhrase__: {//results for given search params
        lastUpdateTime: 1516177824890,//last update time helps to refresh data in background
        pages: {    //each page is stored. You can adjust history length
          '1': {
            isFetching: false,//each page has fetching status
            isRefreshing: false,
            isSuccess: true,
            isFailed: false,
            lastUpdateTime: 1516177824891,
            elements: [ //in 'elements' array only ids are stored. Results are normalized
              100000,
              100001,
                ...
            ]
          }
        },
        elementsCount: 800
      },
      searchPhrase_a_: { //results for "a" search phrase
        lastUpdateTime: 1516177844624,
        pages: {
          '1': {
            isFetching: false,
            isRefreshing: false,
            isSuccess: true,
            isFailed: false,
            lastUpdateTime: 1516177844624,
            elements: [
              100001,
              100016,
              100017,
              100031,
              100044,
              100046,
              100049,
              100055,
              100056,
              100058,
              100065,
              100076,
              100077,
              100084,
              100088
            ]
          }
        },
        elementsCount: 138
      }
    },
    entities: { //here are stored entities. Entities are not duplicated. 
      '100000': {
        examData: 'BVUGUN',
        examIndexAtAll: 0,
        id: 100000
      },
      '100001': {
        examData: 'ZR7ADV',
        examIndexAtAll: 1,
        id: 100001
      },
        ...
    },
    paginationParams: {},
    searchParams: {
      searchPhrase: 'al'
    },
    currentPage: {
      pageNumber: 1
    }
  }
}
```

This json is copied directly from redux. 
Additionally you get features like refreshing results in background, simple use of virtualized list, storing last visited page and many others. 
If you want to use it in multiple lists I suggest to use [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect).

Comment: This pagination tree looks more pretty nice. I like the idea of keying the pagination state tree by a search parameter like `searchPrase_a_`. That package looks like it won't mesh well with my setup, but I definitely will take some inspiration from it. Thanks!

Comment: What's the problem to use this lib in your case? If you have any ideas how to simplify usability, feel free to let me know.

Comment: Well a biggie for me is that the library wants me to use thunk middleware, and I'm partial to using a Redux-API-middleware style. Calling the API is tightly coupled to my middleware. Nowhere in my action creators do they leverage a function to call my API, and I wouldn't want to mix the two. And the pagination library seems like it would take a good minute to familiarize myself with. I'm having a little bit of trouble understanding what exactly it needs from me, and how to use it a high-level.

Comment: It was hard to simplify the API for me. At the moment I think that this library is overcomplicated and it introduces new complications (update and manage redux state). Maybe better approach is to optimize serverside searching engine.